# Is there an existing photo storing cloud that organises photos into albums that can be called from an app?

Tags: android, database, cloud, app-inventor

I'm in the process of creating an android application using app inventor. The problem I face is that I do not wish to use the MySQL/php path and want this to be a multi-user cloud based application. Would I be able to achieve this using Google Drive or other similar facilities?

Comment: Have you tried the Google APIs, you may try google+ API it might provide what you need.

Comment: Hi guys sorry if my original question may be seen as off topic. The problem I face is that I do not wish to use the MySQL/php path and want this to be a multi-user cloud based application. Using this route creates another problem like Fel stated, I would need to manage tokens every time the app was deployed, which would prevent this from being a multi user application

Comment: "these guys" asked you to **edit your question** instead of adding a comment... btw you might want to take a look at the Google Drive solution, there is no need to "manage tokens all the time", see my answer... also probably it would be a good idea to take a look, [how stackoverflow works](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)...

Comment: I am new and still learning, apologies. Thank you for your help Taifun.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For **App Inventor** you might have some limitations and probably therefore not all services @fel mentioned are doable...
But you could store the images in Google Drive for all the users, see the [App Inventor - Google Drive interface](http://puravidaapps.com/drive.php).
 And to store the albums and links to the images, you could use a Google Fusiontable, see the [FusionTablesControl component](http://ai2.appinventor.mit.edu/reference/components/storage.html#FusionTablesControl) and the [Pizza Party tutorial](http://appinventor.mit.edu/explore/ai2/pizzaparty.html).

Answer (score 0):

You should try Amazon S3, Google Drive, Dropbox or a similar service. An example application with Amazon S3, Java and Tomcat 7 could be found [here](https://github.com/CloudBees-community/tomcat7-hibernate-s3-clickstart). On Google Drive or Dropbox, you will need to manage a token that I don't like since you need to enable it every time you re-deploy your application.